# C++ Saving/Loading a function as bytes. Getting the size of a function

Tags: c++

Ok so I've used function pointers for some time. I was trying to figure out if this was possible.

First. It IS possible to convert a function pointer into an array of bytes.

It is also possible to reconstruct that function with the bytes in that array.

I would like to save a function into an array of bytes, and lets say save it to a text file (func.dat). Then later read that text file and execute the particular function...
Is it possible? It seems it should be possible the only problem I run across is finding the size of the array that makes up the function.

Is there any way to do this?

```
int func()
{
    return 1+1;
}

int main()
{
    int (*foo)() = func;

    char* data = (char*)func;

    // write all the data
    char* copyFunc = new char[sizeof(func)];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(func); i++)
        copyFunc[i] = data[i];

    int (*constructedFoo)() = (int (*)())copyFunc;

    return 0;
}
```

of course this code won't compile because sizeof does not work for functions, does anyone know how to get the size of a function? Or the size of the function header/footer.

I have tried things like

```
int func()
{
    1+1;
    new char('}');
}
```

Then searched for the } char (as the end of the function) but that size doesn't work.

If your wondering why I need it, it could be used for lets say, sending a function to a remote computer to execute (thinking of parallel processing) Or even saving a function in a file like in my first example to later be used, this can be helpful.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible in C/C++. First of all, functions may not be contiguous in memory in the binary. So there's no definite "size".

Secondly, you can't just load it into another program and execute it because it will violate memory protection (among other things, like address space).

Lastly (if you managed to get this far), all non-relative jumps and references in the function will likely be broken.

EDIT:

The way to go about sending code to remote computers is to send entire (compiled) binaries. Then have the local and remote machines communicate.

Comment: Doesn't C++ however convert the code into assembly, is there no way to get the assembly of a function and re-assemble it? I've seen some shell coding where people coded an array in bytes, made a function out of it and executed it.

Comment: The problem of non-contiguous functions is still there. Anyway, this is the wrong approach to do what you're trying to achieve. The correct way is to send the entire compiled binary to the remote computer and launch it there. Then use networking protocols to make them talk.

Comment: @u8sand: sure, if you have an array of bytes, and it played nicely (position independant, no hard coded memory references, etc) you can execute it (like shellcode). The problem is in creating this array of bytes from high level code in a way that would be useful in the first place. Compilers aren't usually designed to do that, they are designed to emit efficient code. Which may not be a nice contiguous stream of bytes at all, will probably make memory references to things it knows are in given locations and makes other assumptions about the state of the program, etc.

Comment: Don't forget the function is actually machine code which may not work on the target platform.

Comment: @John Dibling: Correct, there's too many incompatibilities like this to list.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is actually a way how to save and load bytes of code and even run them. This is a great arcicle about that:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/Self-generating-code.aspx?msg=2633508#xx2633508xx

Answer (score 0):

One thing you *can* do if you want dynamically loaded functions:

- Create a dynamic library containing your functions (`.dll` or `.so`)
- Export those symbols with `extern "C"` and if necessary `declspec(dllexport)`
- Load the library at runtime with `LoadLibrary()` or `dlopen()`
- Extract a particular symbol with `GetProcAddress()` or `dlsym()`
- Execute it with [`libffi`](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).
- Clean up after yourself with `FreeLibrary()` or `dlclose()`